# Amazon MWS Product API : How to determine Prime eligible

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I have been currently working with the Amzon MWS Product API for getting the lowest listing price. I would just want to know if there is a way that i can determine that this price is Prime eligible? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Product API you cannot identify whether the item is prime eligible or not, but instead you can try the following API calls to get the price offers

[GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU.html)

If you are using `Product Advertising API`, You can perform an `ItemSearch` the ResponseGroup will contain `IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping` which will tell you if it is Prime eligible.

Note:- Before associating prime items, you have to migrate to new shipping settings

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an `ItemSearch`, the `ResponseGroup` will contain `IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping` which tells you if it is Prime eligible.